# Why do pairing and condensation occur simultaneously in superconductors?

Tags: superconductivity, superfluidity, bose-einstein-condensate

Bose condensation in the weak-coupling limit (such as BCS superconductors) and the strong-coupling limit (like BECs of atoms) can be unified into a single framework by [the BEC-BCS crossover.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176066/bcs-bec-crossover) One key feature distinguishing the BCS side from BEC is that the pairing of fermions near the Fermi surface into Cooper pairs and the condensation of those Cooper pairs happens simultaneously at the same temperature.

1. Is there a simple argument to understand why this is so?
2. For a usual BCS-type interaction, at what interaction strength does this break down? Is there a known expression for the difference, as a function of interaction strength, between the temperature at which pairs become bound and $T_c$ for them to condense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) On the Bose side pairs form when the temperature is lower than the binding energy, $k_BT<B$. Note that this is not a sharp phase transition, and there is no order parameter associated with it. Pairs condense at the Einstein temperature 
$$
 T_c = \frac{2\pi\hbar^2}{mk_B} \left( \frac{n}{\zeta(3/2)}\right)^{2/3}
$$
where $n$ is the density of pairs, and $m\simeq 2m_a$ is the mass of a pair. This is a sharp phase transition (Bose condensation). The pair formation and BEC temperatures become equal when $T_c\sim B$.

Note that parametrically, $T_c$ is on the order of the would-be Fermi energy $E_F=k_F^2/(2m_a)$ of the fermionic constituents. Here, $k_F$ is defined via the density of the gas, $n_F=k_F^3/(3\pi^2)$. The pair density is $n=n_F/2$. This means that the crossover estimate $T_c\sim B$ is roughly consistent with the dimensional estimate $T_F\sim B$.

2) Coming from the BCS side the interaction is weak, and in 3d there are no bound states in vacuum. This means that Cooper pairs form at the BCS transition temperature 
$$
T_c = \frac{8e^\gamma E_F}{(4e)^{1/3}e^2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{\pi}{2k_F|a|}
\right)
$$
where $a$ is the scattering length. The crossover is reached when $T_c$ is of order $E_F$, corresponding to $a\to \infty$.

3) We know that the crossover is smooth (no other phase transitions intervene). This has been established experimentally, by numerical simulation, and is consistent with simple many-body theories. At $a\to\infty$ there is some discussion about a possible "pseudo-gap" phase above $T_c$. This is hard to settle, because there is no completely sharp definition of what a pseudo-gap is.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is helpful. Maybe I can refine my question to this: In the BCS limit and just above $T_c$, is there still some (possibly small) number of fermions in the low-energy part of the thermal distribution that form noncondensed Cooper pairs? Do these pairs exist but are generally ignored because they don't contribute much to thermodynamic properties? And if not, why not?

Comment: One final way of phrasing the same question: if you sit at 1.1 $T_c$ and move from the BEC to BCS limit, does the number of atoms in non-condensed bound pairs just smoothly asymptote towards zero, or does it actually become precisely zero at some finite interaction strength?

Comment: There is no sharp transition, and not even a sharp definition of an operator that would correspond to the "fraction of pre-formed pairs". Having said this, there is no reason to expect any pre-formed pairs on the BCS side. There are no bound states in vacuum, and the BCS wvae function does not predict pre-formed pairs.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. There is still something not clicking here for me, but I might just need to sit with this. I don't see how the statement "There are no bound states in vacuum" is relevant, since the ground state is a filled Fermi sea instead of a vacuum. That's why pairing is possible with an arbitrarily weak attraction, right? So why wouldn't this happen above $T_c$ too?

Comment: Well, I'm just asking what the possible reasons are for expecting bound states. 1) Bound states already exist in vacuum (not the case on the BCS) side, 2) we have a many-body wave function, and it predicts pair correlatons above $T_c$. Possibility 2) is of course an option, but deep on the BCS side the BCS variational wave function is reliable, and it does not predict pair correlations above $T_c$. (Roughly, it is "too simple". It has only one variational parameter related to pair correlations, and that parameter goes to zero at $T_c$).

Comment: @Thomas, I think OP would want to know whether pre-formed pairs would exist above Tc independent of the BCS wavefunction that is used to describe the ground state below Tc. I also echo OP's concern that "no bound states in the vacuum" is not really an appropriate description since we are discussing a Fermi sea ground state.

Comment: In the (extreme) BCS limit the BCS wave function is reliable, so there are indeed (essentially) no pairs above $T_c$. In the BEC limit we observe ideal Bose gas physics, so there are pairs above $T_c$. The trouble is that in the crossover regime there is no sharp definition of what we mean by "preformed pairs". The true wave function, which in any case we don't know, has all sorts of complicated correlations. There is no observable that measures the number of preformed pairs.

Comment: Okay, I will limit myself to one more variation of the question: let's say we use statistics as a proxy for pairing. In the BEC limit above $T_c$ we observe Bose statistics, and in the BCS limit we see Fermi statistics. But is the transition between these gradual? Should we expect some deviation from perfect Fermi statistics that vanishes as the attractive interaction approaches zero, and which would in principle give some "hint" of the Bose-condensed ground state above $T_c$? Or is this ill-defined or nonsensical in some way that I don't see?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple observable that tells you the statistics of the quasi-particles, unless the quasi-particles are weakly interacting (in weak coupling you can look at the T-scaling of the specific heat, for example). This means we can confirm dominances of fermions on BCS side, and bosons on the BEC side, but the crossover is murky.